# blank line in value of field 'Description' while creating deb package

Tags: debian, deb

I want to create a debian package, when i try below command it is giving me error

```
dpkg-deb --build installer_1.0-1
dpkg-deb: error: parsing file 'installer_1.0-1/DEBIAN/control' near line 8   package 'installer':
blank line in value of field 'Description'
```

I've added comment with space in Description, eventhough it is giving me error

Comment: do what's the content of your `debian/control`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any multiline field in debian/control cannot have blank lines.
If you want an empty line in the description, you can add one by adding a line containing a single dot.

e.g.

```
Description: foo-making deviation of fnorz
 fnurgel is a deviation of fnorz that is enhanced by foo-making
 capabilities.
 .
 Above appears an empty line.
```